# Filtering 2 dictionaries json Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, filter, format

I am trying to write a code that only prints the `file1`s `value` variable output of the `sub-dictionaries` so `{'StrategyNumber': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'value': 3000}`s `value` output which would be `3000` . `file1` and `file2` are matching if the `Openningdate` and `Closingdate`  of `file2` are not empty then I want to get the `value` output of the sub-dictionary. How would I be able to get the `Expected Output`?

Dictionaries:

```
file1={'RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 1, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'value': 100}], 'MOM': [{'StrategyNumber': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'value': 3000}, {'StrategyNumber': 3, 'TradingPair': 'ETHUSDT', 'value': 22}], 'MOM_RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 4, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'value': 4556}, {'StrategyNumber': 5, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSDT', 'value': 234}]}
file2={'RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 1, 'Openningdate': [], 'Closingdate': []}], 'MOM': [{'StrategyNumber': 2, 'Openningdate': [324284], 'Closingdate': [23234]}, {'StrategyNumber': 3, 'Openningdate': [324235456, 78475], 'Closingdate': [232343435, 45678756]}], 'MOM_RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 4, 'Openningdate': [], 'Closingdate': []}, {'StrategyNumber': 5, 'Openningdate': [777, 88, 9, 10], 'Closingdate': [10, 476, 3456, 45]}]
```

Code for filter:

```
for Strats in file2:
    for Strats_info in file2[Strats]:
        for momentum_filter in file1[Strats]:
            if len(Strats_info["Openningdate"]) > 0 and len(Strats_info["Closingdate"]) > 0:
                print(momentum_filter['value'])
```

Output:

```
3000
22
3000
22
4556
234
```

Expected Output:

```
3000
24
234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` to pair up the same `Strats_info` with the same `momentum_filter`:

```py
file1 = {'RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 1, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'value': 100}],
         'MOM': [{'StrategyNumber': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'value': 3000},
                 {'StrategyNumber': 3, 'TradingPair': 'ETHUSDT', 'value': 22}],
         'MOM_RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 4, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'value': 4556},
                     {'StrategyNumber': 5, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSDT', 'value': 234}]}

file2 = {'RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 1, 'Openningdate': [], 'Closingdate': []}],
         'MOM': [{'StrategyNumber': 2, 'Openningdate': [324284], 'Closingdate': [23234]},
                 {'StrategyNumber': 3, 'Openningdate': [324235456, 78475], 'Closingdate': [232343435, 45678756]}],
         'MOM_RSI': [{'StrategyNumber': 4, 'Openningdate': [], 'Closingdate': []},
                     {'StrategyNumber': 5, 'Openningdate': [777, 88, 9, 10], 'Closingdate': [10, 476, 3456, 45]}]}

for Strats in file2:
    for Strats_info,momentum_filter in zip(file2[Strats],file1[Strats]):
            if len(Strats_info["Openningdate"]) > 0 and len(Strats_info["Closingdate"]) > 0:
                print(momentum_filter['value'])
```

Output:

```
3000
22
234
```

Comment: Thank you that works I am also trying to append the whole `momentum_filter` with each iteration to into a separate dictionary `new_dict= {}`. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: @georgehere Ask another question with your attempt and desired output.  I'm not quite sure what you want since the momentum filters are lists of dicts, not just a dict.